# Navigation bar disappears with CSS animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I am using the CSS3 animations from the Animate.css library. They are real nice and they work perfectly when I combine them with WOW.js

However, when I am scrolling down the page and the animations go into the screen, my fixed navigation bar on top of the screen disappears for a couple seconds, the time the animation is displaying, and then it goes back into the screen.

How can I avoid this to happen? I don´t want my fixed navigation bar to disappear, ever.

Comment: can you show us demo? it will be easier to debug

Comment: I just found out that the problem is not happening in Firefox or Internet Explorer. It happens in Google Chrome. This is really hurting my site though. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905941/blinking-fixed-header-in-site-with-scrolling-animation/20907500

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563612/css3-animations-breaking-fixed-positioning-when-page-scrolled

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! After many tries I deleted the z-index property of the fixed navbar section and now it doesn´t disappear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches to solve this problem.

1.) The first one (which did not work for me) is to attach:

```
.your_element_with_position_fixed {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

to your "floating elements" which have the `position: fixed;` attribution.

2.) The second approach (which did work for me together with Animate.css, WOW.js and AOS) is to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` or your container elements which contain the animation e.g. `section`. Use this rule within your CSS file:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

or

```
section { overflow-x: hidden; } // or any other container element which contains your animation
```

I stumbled over this solution [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/274) within an issue in the AOS repository. Additionally the problem was also discussed [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/741) for animate.css. Hope this solution helps someone who is desperately searching for a fix. This was the only thing that helped fixing the problem for me.